# How to get valid access token to call Azure REST API from Postman

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory, azure-container-instances, azure-rest-api

I want to be able to call the Azure rest APIs for creating/reading resources like Container instances, Container registries and storage accounts.

In my Azure AD, I registered an app for my application and got clientID, secret, and tenantId.

I have called the following API to get the token:

> `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/token`

with

**resource, client_id, client_secret and grant_type**

as body parameters in the `POST` request

The token I receive from here is not working fine. I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client 'ff70fcft-21ub-4a7f-8h20-3f405c5d17e0' with object id 'ff70fcff-22bb-4a7f-9f20-3f405c1e17e0' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/afb6001a-XXXX-4c39-XXXX-9706012c30ba/resourceGroups/app2/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/app2' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
    }
}
```

However, When I copy the access token from Browser's Network tab, it works fine.

I believe that something is not right with app-registration because it feel app and my resources are currently disconnected.

Can anyone please help me out in this?

Update:
[image]

Comment: Which api do you want to call?

Comment: @TonyJu

I was trying to hit this one: GET management.azure.com/subscriptions{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/{containerGroupName}?api-version=2018-10-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you didn't grant Azure subscription access permission to your registered application.

Here are the steps:

1.All services->Subscriptions->choose your subscription-> click Access controll

[image]

2.Click Add to add role assignment to your registered application

[image]

3.Get the access token to access the api again, it will work.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal#overview-of-access-control-iam

**Update:**

Please choose the correct subscription.

[image]

Comment: what I am not getting is, when I type something in Select* textfield, I can't find my resource, and is shows "No container instance managed identities found in this subscription". I have already reached the step you suggested, but couldn't go beyond that

Comment: @AyushOjha In step2, you should assign access to your registered application. Can you check if you created the container instance in the same subscription?

Comment: @AyushOjha See the updates in the answer, maybe you have more than one subscription.

Comment: Yes it is in the same subscription.

Comment: @AyushOjha Let's analyze the issue. You can call the api by click 'try it' here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containergroups/get, right? If so, did you add role assignment under the same subscription? If yes, it doesn't make sense that you got that error.

Comment: when i try the API on doc reference page, it works because it uses my access token from my login credentials, but when I try on postman, the token i get is not correct is much shorter than the one that is working, seems it doesn't have enough permissions. I have a role assignment of owner and contributor in the subscription.

Comment: @AyushOjha That's why I ask you to assign role assignment to the application you registered(step2). You have a client_id, you should search by the client name and select the application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201240/discussion-between-ayush-ojha-and-tony-ju).